# Multiple Web.config files in Area using ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a question on something that I thought would be a simple. I have an Area in my website and I'd like to create a Web.config file specific to this area but, no matter where I put this config file, the keys that I've set up in my appSettings are all returning "null" when I access them, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Here's my website structure:

```
Site
    [usual site stuff like Views, Models, Controllers] 
    Web.config
    Areas
        MyArea
            Web.config
            [usual site stuff like Views, Models, Controllers]
```

my web.config on the main site looks something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyMainKey" value="MyTestValue"/>
</appSettings>
<!--all of the standard asp.net mvc config stuff -->
</configuration>
```

My areas config looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyAreaConfigValue" value="MyAreaTestValue"/>
</appSettings>
<!--all of the standard asp.net mvc config stuff -->
</configuration>
```

In a controller action that exists in my Areas/MyArea/Controllers folder I'm trying to access it like so:

```
string my_area_config_val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAreaTestValue"];
```

But my_area_config_val is null.

In a controller action in my main site (not in my Area) I can do

```
string my_main_config_val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyTestValue"];
```

and my_main_config_val is equal to "MyTestVal", as expected.

Thanks.
Mustafa

Comment: You're going to need to post your web.config data as well.  Also, some code where you are accessing the data.

Comment: Edited my question to add more config data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Web.config` file goes in the `Area/Views` dir. I have not found any concrete facts, but from what I have seen in doing some research is that the `<appSettings>` from `Web.config` files within Areas will never get used. Below is one site that has a brief statement on it:

- [AREAS in ASP.NET MVC 2.0](http://mstechkb.blogspot.com/2010/10/areas-in-aspnet-mvc-20.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - too bad it isn't supported.